# Unable to Deploy Diaspora on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, heroku-toolbelt

Initially i had set the proxy of my git to 192.168.0.9 which is now not working so i used

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
$ set http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port
$ export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port
```

to change the proxy to 192.168.0.5
but when i run

```
$ heroku create
```

in git bash it says internal server error and displays HTTP PROXY = 192.168.0.9

can you please help me with the command so that i can change the proxy.

Comment: I'm a newbi.. working on ruby on rails  for just last 24 hrs and have to deploy disapora on Heroku but due to this i'm unable to and getting delayed. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an installment guide from diaspora for heroku, https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Installing-on-heroku. You might want to find a tutorial for working with heroku. Why did you change your proxy?

Comment: i changed my proxy because the one which i used earlier was disabled by the institute so had to change it

Comment: I tried following the tutorial link you gave, but i'm having same problem the proxy which i'm setting up. It's not taking it. It's stuck at 192.168.0.9
Can you list all the commands which are used to set proxy in git bash